# What is the "Git aware transport mechanism" to which the git clone docs refer?

Tags: git, git-clone

The [git clone](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) documentation has this passage:

> **--local**
>
> [...] this flag bypasses the normal "Git aware" transport mechanism [...]

What is meant here by "the normal 'Git aware' transport mechanism"?

Answer (score 0):

Git chooses cloning protocol from repository URL. And that's meant by *"the normal 'Git aware' transport mechanism"*. From URL:

```
file:///path/to/repo.git/
```

Git knows that repository located locally and uses simple file transfer (or even hardlinking) for cloning. But if you don't use an URL, just a local path:

```
/path/to/repo.git/
```

than Git implies `--local` option and uses alternative, non-URL transport recognition.
See [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS) for `git clone` URL.